Hide "Backordered" item metadata from customer Orders and Email notifications in WooCommerce
Currently, have the WooCommerce Backorder feature enabled, but would like to remove form notifications 'Backordered: 1' from the WooCommerce Orders Panel, all email notifications, receipts, delivery notes etc.


Is this possible with custom PHP via a child theme functions.php file?
Unfortunately, I didn't find yet any way to do it.
I have done some Google searching, but, all I have found is articles about renaming the $string rather than hiding/removing it.

As this order item metadata is displayed via WC_Order_Item get_formatted_meta_data() method, you can use woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data dedicated filter hook, to hide any specific order item metadata to be displayed.
The following, will hide "Backordered" metadata from customer orders and email notifications:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data', 'hide_specific_order_item_metadata', 10, 2);
function hide_specific_order_item_metadata($formatted_meta, $item){
    if( is_admin() ) return $formatted_meta; // Exit if Admin orders

    foreach( $formatted_meta as $key => $meta ){
        if( $meta->key === 'Backordered' ) {
            unset($formatted_meta[$key]);
        }  
    }
    return $formatted_meta;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.
For some third party plugins, you may use their own hooks…
If you also want to hide it from Admin single order, just remove the first line inside the function.
Note that if you want to get rid of that without any code, you can change that on single product settings: For "Allow backorders?" option, select "Allow" instead of "Allow, but notify customer":

